# List only unvisited links with document.links

Tags: javascript, css, hyperlink, userscripts

I'm listing all of the links to the bottom of some websites with `document.links` (with a userscript).

Visited and unvisited url-s are appearing together. I can set different colors to them so it is easy to see which links are new and which ones I visited already. But I'd like to see **only** the new links.

Is there a way to tell `document.links` to list only the unvisited (new) (`a:link`) links?

(If not possible, then how could I hide the visited links? I've tried `visibility:hidden;` and  `display:none;` on `a:visited` , but not working. Found out it is a [privacy related](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2010/03/privacy-related-changes-coming-to-css-vistited/) thing, but I don't want to touch the links on the original page, only in my link collection which is a copy of those.)

Comment: Just tried `document.querySelectorAll("a:visited")` and it doesn’t seem to work… As far as I know you can’t reliably get those links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Possibly Not Possible**

I'm not entirely sure how possible that this will be [due to the security issue similar to the one you mentioned in this similar article](https://blog.mozilla.org/security/2010/03/31/plugging-the-css-history-leak/) that have resulted in the `:visited` selector being severely restricted, making programmatic access nearly impossible in modern browsers.

**Workaround Through `localStorage`**

I suppose that [you could use a workaround similar to the one mentioned in this blog post](http://nevyan.blogspot.com/2013/07/mark-visited-links-using-javascript-and.html), which uses localStorage to explicitly store the links that were clicked on and persist "visited" attributes so that you can identify those that have been touched :

```
function check_visited_links(){
    // Access all of the elements that have been visited (from local storage)
    var visited_links = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('visited_links')) || [];
    // Iterate through your links
    var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
    for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
        var that = links[i];
        // When the link is clicked, store a reference in localStorage to it
        that.onclick = function () {
            var clicked_url = this.href;
            if (visited_links.indexOf(clicked_url)==-1) {
                visited_links.push(clicked_url);
                localStorage.setItem('visited_links', JSON.stringify(visited_links));
            }
        } 
        // Indicate the link was visited by setting it's class
        if (visited_links.indexOf(that.href)!== -1) { 
            that.className += ' visited';
        }
    }
}
```

This approach would append a "visited" class to your elements and would allow you to explicitly remove them by either using a purely CSS approach :

```
a.visited { display: none; }
```

Or by using a Javascript technique similar to the one you originally used via :

```
document.querySelectorAll('a.visited');
```

**Example Using `localStorage` Technique**

You can [see an example that uses the `localStorage` technique here](http://jsbin.com/vepijuw/2/edit?html,js,output) (just reload after each button press for example purposes) and an example of its output below :

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Though - unfortunately - this (local storage) is not an option for me as there would be a huge amount of links in that in a short time, which would slow down everything I guess (+ my HDD is too slow/old). Currently I am setting the color for "a:visited" the same as the background of the given website. Seeing a big empty space with a few links in it is not that nice. The idea would be for that div (with the d.links) to appear only when new links are available.

Comment: Local Storage shouldn't necessarily slow things down assuming you aren't storing unnecessarily huge amounts in there. As mentioned, the `:visited` pseudoclass will likely not work at all using newer browsers, so the only real way to handle this would be to implement a solution that allowed you to store which links had been clicked on. If you were to use a solution like the proposed one, you could easily use jQuery to determine if a `<div>` contained any lists that were not visited and show/hide it accordingly.